# Jython how to print the class path

Tags: websphere, jython

I have a problem loading a module in jython in websphere. The .py files are in a jar which is itself in a war which is itself in an ear. Those modules are loading well when not embedded in websphere.

I guess my jython path is incorrect, so I tried to print the path with `print sys.path`.
The result is:

```
['__classpath__', '__pyclasspath__/']
```

How to print the content of those built-in properties ?

Answer (score 4):

Don't know whether it is possible in "pure" Jython, but here's how to do it in Java:

```
from java.lang import ClassLoader
cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
paths = map(lambda url: url.getFile(), cl.getURLs())
print paths
```

Comment: I tested your code in Jython 2.7b3 and yes, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing even a snippet of you Jython code I can't be sure if this answers your question:

http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/ModulesPackages.html#advanced-import-manipulation

The fact that WebSphere is bundled with ancient version of Jython (v2.1 released 10 years ago) certainly won't help you...